# BindingResolutionException and Target is not instantiable

Tags: php, laravel

**Error:**

```
BindingResolutionException in Container.php line 887:
Target [App\Helpers\Contracts\AccessTokenInterface] is not instantiable.
```

**Route:**

```
Route::get('/', 'LoginController@handleProviderCallback');
```

**Controller:**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Helpers\Contracts\AccessTokenInterface;

class LoginController extends Controller
{

    public function handleProviderCallback(AccessTokenInterface $accessTokenInstance)
    {

        return $accessTokenInstance->getSomething();
    }
}
```

**Provider:**

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\Helpers\Contracts\AccessTokenInterface;
use AccessToken;

class TokenServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $defer = true;

    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(AccessTokenInterface::class, function(){
            return new AccessToken();
        });
    }
}
```

**Helper:**

```
namespace App\Helpers;

use App\Helpers\Contracts\AccessTokenInterface;

class AccessToken implements AccessTokenInterface
{
    protected $something;

    public function setSomething()
     {
        $something = 100;
     }

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->setSomething();
    }

    public function getSomething(){
        return $something;
    }
```

**Interface:**

```
namespace App\Helpers\Contracts;

Interface AccessTokenInterface
{

    public function getSomething();
    public function setSomething();
}
```

I have registered **Provider in providers** and **AccessToken in aliases for Helper**.

I have read some stackoverflow answers but can't find solution. I am new to this.

Where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Write in your **config/app.php**

```
'providers' => [
    ...
    App\Providers\TokenServiceProvider::class,
    ...
]
```

Hope it help you :)